# ¿Da igual usar #include <iostream> o #include "iostream"?

Tags: c++

Ayer escribí por error `#include "iostream"` y no me he dado cuenta porque el compilador no ha dado error. Más tarde me he dado cuenta y me ha sorprendido.

He probado con este pequeño programa :

```
// Fichero a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#endif // A_H

// Fichero a.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Hola Mundo" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

El cual funciona como es de esperar.
También funciona si pongo los dos includes con comillas dobles `" "`, esto me ha sorprendido.
Si los pongo los dos includes con menor mayor `< >` me da un error de compilación, que es lo que espero :

> a.cpp:2:15: fatal error: a.h: No such file or directory

Yo pensaba que :

- `#include < >` es para cabeceras de sistema o librerías.
- `#include " "` es para cabeceras del programador.

Pero está claro que no porque iostream también se puede incluir con `" "`.
¿Puedo simplemente incluirlo todo con `" "`?
¿O podría tener algún efecto adverso el hacerlo todo con `" "`? Y si es así, ¿qué criterio usar para decidir cada include si se hace con `" "` o `< >`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Efectivamente, ambos *includes* no son necesariamente intercambiables.

```
#include <archivo>
```

Este tipo de *include* intenta localizar el archivo en los directorios del sistema. Si el archivo en cuestión no es posible encontrarlo la compilación terminará con un error.

```
#include "archivo"
```

Este otro *include* busca el archivo en la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo actual. Si la búsqueda resulta infructuosa entonces se intenta localizar el archivo en los directorios del sistema. Este *include* es, por tanto, más completo que la versión con brackets.

Pese a que un proyecto puede compilar perfectamente si todos los *includes* se escriben con comillas, no es una práctica especialmente recomendable. Hay que tener en cuenta que las compilaciones en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pueden ser largas hasta el aburrimiento. Obligar al compilador a realizar búsquedas genéricas no ayuda a que el tiempo de compilación se reduzca. Incluir las librerías del sistema con brackets reduce el abanico de búsqueda y eso repercute en un tiempo de compilación sensiblemente menor (obviamente cuanto más grande sea el proyecto más se notará este efecto).

Por otro lado, distinguir entre *includes* locales (con comillas) y del sistema (con brackets) aumenta ligeramente la legibilidad del código. Permite saber, de un rápido vistazo, si el archivo en cuestión se encuentra en el directorio del proyecto o si, en cambio, se corresponde con una librería externa.

Comment: Diablos, no lo sabía.