# Directivas del preprocesador de C++

Tags: c++, preprocesador

Tengo el siguiente código en C++

```
#define NULL 0
int main {
    int a = NULL;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

La sentencia #define me sirve para definir constantes como NULL. ¿Es eso cierto o tiene más usos? ¿Existen otras directivas de preprocesador además de #define que me ayuden a mejorar el desarrollo de mis aplicaciones?

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta es demasiado amplia/extensa para SOes. ¿Podrías acotarla a un caso específico? por ejemplo: para que sirve la directiva `pragma`?

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia, no entiendo lo que es la wiki de la comunidad pero creo que deberia ir alli

Comment: Venga ya. Puesta en espera como ... ¿¿¿ ¡¡¡ Se Basa Principalmente en Opiniones !!! ??? Esto no es serio.

Comment: @Trauma Imagino que ya lo has hecho, pero si quieres que se reabra puedes votar en [Reabriendo:¿Cómo funciona el preprocesador de C++?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2184/reabriendo-c%c3%b3mo-funciona-el-preprocesador-de-c). Respecto al motivo de cierre, tradicionalmente no le dan mucha importancia en meta. Es habitual cerrar por motivo incorrecto pero si el cierre se considera correcto no se le da importancia al motivo. Es lo que hay. Lo correcto sería "fuera de ámbito" pues me han dejado claro que no hay forma de reescribir la pregunta para que la acepten quienes así votaron.

Comment: Voté en meta hace días, en cuanto la vi. No me parece correcto el trato dado a esta pregunta; no hay mas que mirar los ejemplos que indicas en Meta, que **siguen abiertos y con bastantes votos**. El sitio estará graduado, pero la comunidad no. Se está confundiendo a la persona (que nos puede caer mejor o peor) con la calidad/utilidad de las preguntas y respuestas.

Answer (score 5):

## Función.

El preprocesador recibe un fichero de entrada y lo transforma en uno de salida aplicando las directivas incluidas en el fichero de entrada. Estas directivas permiten incluir código de otros ficheros (habitualmente archivos de cabecera), substituir unos textos por otros (esto son las macros) y elegir si se incluye o no cierto código (esto es la compilación condicional).
El preprocesador solo entiende las directivas de preprocesado, las cuales empiezan por `#`. No entiende el lenguaje C++, no sabe que es un `int` o un `std::vector`.
Es la primera fase de las 3 tradicionales fases de compilación de un programa C++<sup>1</sup>:

- Preprocesado
- Compilado
- Enlazado

## Directivas standard

El standard de C++ define las siguientes directivas: define, undef, include, if, ifdef, ifndef, else, elif, endif, line, error, pragma

## `#define`

Sirve para declarar una macro. Un texto que será substituido por otro por el preprocesador. Por ejemplo, el siguiente fichero:

```
#define MIMACRO 17
int main() {
  return MIMACRO;
}
```

Al ser traducido por el preprocesador se convertirá en :

```
int main() {
  return 17;
}
```

Esta directiva también permite el uso de parámetros, por ejemplo:

```
#define SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO(nombre,lista) \
    std::cout<<"Hola " << nombre <<std::endl;\
    lista.push_back(nombre)

#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
int main(void) {
  std::vector listaNombres;
  SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO("Marta", listaNombres);
  SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO("Luis", listaNombres);
  SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO("Lucas", listaNombres);
  SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO("Ana", listaNombres);
  std::cout << "Registrados:" << std::endl;
  for( const std::string& nombre: listaNombres )
    std::cout << nombre << std:endl;
  return 0;
}
```

En el programa anterior la macro `SALDO_Y_REGISTRO` permite dos parámetros. Uno es impreso en std::cout junto con un saludo. Y el otro se utiliza para hacer añadir el nombre a un contenedor que soporte push_back.
La macro anterior tiene un problema, considera este código:

```
if ( alguna_condicion)
   SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO("Lucas", listaNombres);
```

El código anterior se traduce como:

```
if ( alguna_condicion)
    std::cout<<"Hola " << "Lucas" <<std::endl;\
    listaNombres.push_back("Lucas");
```

Con lo que a "Lucas" se le saluda solo si se cumple la condición pero se le registra siempre. Que probablemente no es lo que quería el autor. Fíjate que aunque la última línea esté identada esta no pertenece al if. El if actua solo sobre el siguiente bloque.
Esto se puede arreglar con llaves:

```
if ( alguna_condicion) {
   SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO("Lucas", listaNombres);
}
```

Pero esto es muy propenso a errores, tener que acordarse de usar llaves con ciertas macros no es cómodo. Una mejor solución es la técnica del do-while que se ejecuta siempre una vez:

```
#define SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO(nombre,lista) \
  do { \
    std::cout<<"Hola " << nombre <<std::endl;\
    lista.push_back(nombre) \
  } while(false)
```

Con esa macro puedes usar SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO de forma similar a una función, todo su código formará un solo bloque.

Usar macros como si fuesen funciones puede ser tentador puesto que el código se inserta diréctamente en el resultado final en vez de tener que hacer llamadas a subrutinas y retornos. El resultado es un programa más rápido y más grande. Pero no es recomendable. Perdemos entre otras cosas la seguridad de tipos (type safety). Y con compiladores optimizadores modernos no es necesario, son capaces de optimizar funciones de la misma forma.

Es tradicional y recomendable definir las macros utilizando letras mayúsculas y separando palabras por guiones bajos.

#### `#undef`

La definición de una macro (definida con `#define`) dura hasta que su definición es cancelada con `#undef`.

Por ejemplo, el programa siguiente dará un error de compilación:

```
#define MIMACRO 17
int res = MIMACRO;
int main() {
  int MIMACRO;
  MIMACRO = 33;
  return res;
}
```

No podemos utilizar MIMACRO como nombre de variable porque el preprocesador lo substituye por 17. Y 17 no es un nombre de variable válido.
El siguiente programa sí compila bien.
    #define MIMACRO 17
    int res = MIMACRO;
    int main() {
    #undef MIMACRO
      int MIMACRO;
      MIMACRO = 33;
      return res;
    }

`#undef` cancela la definición de macro MIMACRO. Por lo que el preprocesador ya no la va a substituir por 17 despues del `#undef` permitiendo así usarlo como nombre de variable. Entre el `#define` y el `#undef` MIMACRO sí es substituido por 17, por lo que la variable global `res` es inicializada a 17.

#### `#include`

Esta directiva recive como parámetro un nombre de fichero. El parámetro se puede dar entre comillas o entre símbolos <>. Para la diferencia entre estas dos formas ver [¿Da igual usar #include  o #include “iostream”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1959/da-igual-usar-include-iostream-o-include-iostream)
La directiva lee ese fichero y lo inserta en el fichero que está procesando, en el punto en que se encontraba la directiva. Nótese que estos ficheros insertados también son preprocesados y pueden a su vez tener otros `#include` con lo que pude haber una cascada de código insertado.

Por ejemplo considérense tres ficheros:

```
// Fichero sumas.h
int suma(int a,int b);

// fichero restas.h
int resta(int a, int b);

// Fichero main.cpp
#include "sumas.h"
#include "restas.h"
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Si ejecutamos el preprocesador contra el fichero main.cpp el resultado final será:

```
int suma(int a,int b);
int resta(int a,int b);
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

## `#ifdef, #ifndef, #else, #endif`

Estas cuatro directivas permiter controlar qué codigo va a ser compilado en función de si las macros utilizadas como parámetros están o no definidas.

Por ejemplo, si pasamos el siguiente código al preprocesador:

```
#define LINUX

int main() {
#ifdef LINUX
  std::cout << "Mi SO es Linux" << std::endl;
#else 
  std::cout << "Mi So no es Linux" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifndef MAC
  std::cout << "No uso Macintosh" << std::endl;
#else
  std::cout << "Sí uso Macintosh" << std::endl;
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

Será traducido como:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Mi SO es Linux" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "No uso Macintosh" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

`#ifdef` incluye el código que le sigue si la macro que le acompaña está definida. `#ifndef` hace lo mismo si ls macro no está definida. Ambas deben ir acompañadas de un `#endif` que marca el final de ese código que se compila condicionalmente. Se puede usar `#else` para poner un código alternativo en caso de que no se cumpla la condición.
Es posible anidar estas directivas de forma similar a como se hace con los `if` de C++.

#### `#if, #elif`

`#if` actua como `#ifdef` pero comparando una macro con un valor en vez de en función de si está definida. `#elif` permite encadenar varias comprobaciones seguidas sin tener que anidarlas y necesitando solo un `#endif` al final. Por ejemplo.

```
#DEFINE LINUX 1
#DEFINE NINTENDO 2
#DEFINE VR_VIVE 3
bool disparoPulsado() {
#if SYSTEM == LINUX
  return (key[KEY_SPACE]);
#elif SYSTEM == NINTENDO
  return buttonPressed(KEY_A);
#elif SYSTEM == VR_VIVE
  return pushGesture();
#else
#error Sistema desconocido
#endif
}
```

El código anterior sería el de una hipotética función que determina si un jugador ha pulsado el botón de disparo. Debemos definir la macro SYSTEM con un valor según compilemos para Linux, Nintendo o Realidad Virtual con VIVE. Y según el valor de esa macro se llamará a un código u otro.
Esto también lo podríamos haber hecho con un `if` normal de código de C++. Pero esto tiene un inconveniente, es muy posible que la función `buttonPressed` de Nintendo no exista en Linux y falle la compilación del sistema para Linux. No tiene sentido que falle la compilación por un código que no se va a usar, para eso usamos estas directivas de procesador.

#### `#error`

Esta directiva provoca que falle la compilación y el compilador emita el mensaje de error que acompaña a esta directiva. En el ejemplo de la sección anterior damos un error de "Sistema desconocido" si la macro SYSTEM no está definida a un valor conocido.

#### `#line`

Esta es una macro que posiblemente nunca uses.

```
#line 17
```

Cuando se sigue de un número causa que el compilador trate la siguiente línea como si fuese ese número de línea en vez del número de línea que de verdad tiene. Esto afecta a los mensajes de aviso o error que emita el compilador y a la información de ayuda a depuradores pero no afecta al código generado.

```
#line 17 nombreFichero
```

Si además añades un nombre el compilador actuará como si el fichero que está procesando tuviese este nombre.

Esta directiva es útil para programas de transformación de código. Por ejemplo, los primeros compiladores de C++ traducían el código C++ a C y después lo compilaban con un compilador normal de C. Así se ahorraban escribir el compilador entero. Pero con frecuencia una línea de C se convertía en muchas de C++. Para que el compilador de C diese los números de línea correctos en los mensajes de error usaban esta directiva.

#### `#pragma`

```
#pragma parametros
```

Esta es la directiva de control dependiente de la implementación. Cada compilador puede definir sus propios pragmas con su propio significado.

Un pragma común es `#pragma once`. Si aparece en la primera línea de un fichero indica que ese fichero solo se debe incluir una vez. Es una directiva que no existe en todos los sistemas y que no funciona bien con ficheros montados en red, hardlinks o similares.

#### `##`

`##` no es una directiva sino un operador de macro. Toma dos tokens distintos y los pega para formar un solo token. El token resultado puede ser un nombre de variable, de clase o cualquier otro identificador.

Por ejemplo:

```
#define DECLARA_Y_ASIGNA(tipo, nombrevar, valor) \
  tipo nombrevar = valor;
  tipo original_#nombrevar = valor;

DECLARE_AND_SET( int, area, 2 * 6 );
```

El `#define` anterior se utilizaría como ayuda a la depuración. Te permite declarar y asignar una variable. Pero declarando siempre otra segunda variable que empieza por original_ y sigue con el mismo nombre y a la que se asigna el mismo valor. En tu código usarías la variable con el nombre que pusiste en la macro. Y si mientras estás depurando quieres consultar el valor original puedes consultar la otra variable que se ha declarado con la macro.

#### Guardas de compilación.

Esta es una técnica muy habitual en los archivos de cabecera.
Es común que un archivo de cabecera sea utilizado por varios archivos de cabecera. Por ejemplo

```
//Fichero persona.h
class Persona {
};

//Fichero calculos.h
#include "persona.h"
Edad envejecer(Persona p, int tiempo);

//Fichero impresiones.h
#include "persona.h"
void muestraPersona( Persona p);

//Fichero main.c
#include "calculos.h"
#include "impresiones.h"
/* El resto del código */
```

Al compilar el fichero main.c vamos a tener un error:

> error: redefinition of ‘class Persona’

Esto se debe a que main.c incluye calculos.h e impresiones.h y cada uno de estos dos a su vez incluye a persona.h . Con lo que persona.h ha quedado incluido dos veces y el compilador no admite que la clase Persona se defina dos veces.

Esto podemos solucionarlo así en el fichero tipos.h :

```
#ifndef PERSONA_H
#define PERSONA_H
//Fichero persona.h
class Persona {
};
#endif
```

La primera vez que se incluya el fichero la macro no estará definida por lo que el `#ifndef` se evaluará a cierto y todo el código se incluirá. El código incluido a su vez define la macro PERSONA_H. La siguiente vez que se incluya la macro sí está definida por lo que el `#ifndef` se evalua a falso y no se incluirá el código.
De esta forma nos aseguramos que el código del fichero se incluye una sola vez aunque el archivo se incluya múltiples veces.

Notas a pié de página:

1. El standard de C++ define 9 fases de traducción. El preprocesador se corresponde con las fases 1-6. Puedes ver [esta respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8834196/956880) para más detalles.

Comment: Aqui tienes un pequeno problema, `#define SALUDO_Y_REGISTRO(nombre,lista) \
  do {
    std::cout<<"Hola " << nombre <<std::endl;\
    lista.push_back(nombre) \
  } while(false);` no tiene mucha importacia pero es para que quede bien en la respuesta, no pude editarla pues es solo agregar el ` \ ` al final de `do {`

Comment: @DanielPérez Tienes razón, y además me sobraba el ; después del (false). Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberías añadir la etiqueta `[C]` ¿ no ?. Y supongo que indicar algunas de las macros estándar para controlar la versión del lenguaje sería demasiado, pero haría la respuesta *redonda*. +1 a la pregunta y a la respuesta.

Comment: Si van a añadir la etiqueta `[C]` seria bueno que incluyeran un ejemplo del `#ifdef .. #define ... #endif` para la declaracion de ficheros cabecera en C