# ¿Cómo hago para que no me aparezcan todos los descuentos en mi programa?

Tags: c++

el problema que tengo es que al ejecutar el programa, al poner el monto que se debe pagar, me aparecen todos los descuentos, pero solo me debería aparecer uno de los descuentos, no todos, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo  agradecería mucho.

```
#include "iostream"


//En una tienda efectúan un descuento a los clientes dependiendo del monto de la compra.

//El descuento se efectúa con base en el siguiente criterio.

//Menor a $500 -> No hay descuento.

//Entre $500 y $1000 -> 5% de descuento.

//Entre $1000 y $7000 -> 11% de descuento.

//Entre $7000 y $15000 -> 18% de descuento.

//Mayor a $15000 -> 25% de descuento.

//Construya un programa tal que dado el monto de la compra de un cliente, determine lo que  mismo debe pagar.

using namespace std;

int main()


{

    float COMPRA;
    float PAGAR;

    cout<< "CANTIDAD A COBRAR:";
    cin>> COMPRA;

    if (COMPRA < 500)
    {
        PAGAR = COMPRA;
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR:"<< COMPRA<< endl;
    }
    else (COMPRA <=1000);
    {
        PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.05);
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON 5% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
    }
    if (COMPRA <= 7000)
    {
        PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.11);
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 11% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
    }
    else (COMPRA <= 15000);
    {
        PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.18);
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 18% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
    }
    if (COMPRA > 15000);
    {
        PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.25);
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 25% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c` y `c++` son lenguajes distintos, no los uses a la misma vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las razones del fallo lo explica [@eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion), asi que mi respuesta va a mostrarte una forma más legible del código, como se ve no todo el cálculo debe hacerse en los `if`s sino que puedes reducirlo a que establezcan solo el porcentaje, y al final puedas hacer el cálculo:

```
#include <iostream>

/*
 * En una tienda efectúan un descuento a los clientes dependiendo del monto de la compra.
 * El descuento se efectúa con base en el siguiente criterio:
 * - Menor a $500 -> No hay descuento.
 * - Entre $500 y $1000 -> 5% de descuento.
 * - Entre $1000 y $7000 -> 11% de descuento.
 * - Entre $7000 y $15000 -> 18% de descuento.
 * - Mayor a $15000 -> 25% de descuento
 * Construya un programa tal que dado el monto de la compra de un cliente,
 * determine lo que  mismo debe pagar.
*/

int main()
{
    float compra;
    float total_a_pagar;
    float porcentaje_descuento;

    std::cout << "CANTIDAD A COBRAR:";
    std::cin >> compra;

    if(compra <= 0){
        std::cout << "La compra debe ser positiva\n";
        return -1;
    }
    if(compra < 500){
        porcentaje_descuento = 0;
    }
    else if (compra < 1000) {
        porcentaje_descuento = 5;
    }
    else if (compra < 7000) {
        porcentaje_descuento = 11;
    }
    else if (compra < 15000) {
        porcentaje_descuento = 18;
    }
    else{
        porcentaje_descuento = 25;
    }
    total_a_pagar = compra* (100-porcentaje_descuento)/100.0;
    std::cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL "<<  porcentaje_descuento <<"% DE DESCUENTO ES "<< total_a_pagar <<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Nota:

Cuando importes librerias externas es recomendable usa `<>`, y cuando llames a otros archivos que has creado debes usar `""`. Para más detalles sobre este tema puedes consultar [este otro hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1959/463)

Comment: @eferion obvio, lo sé, al contrario, estaba buscando alguna docs que señale eso, y es mejor que sea de SO para que los usuarios aprendan a hacer una búsqueda antes de preguntar :)

Comment: Es que respondí a esa pregunta... por eso recordaba el tema... sabía lo que estaba buscando :)

Answer (score 2):

El programa se encuentra con un condicional:

```
if (COMPRA < 500)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA;
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR:"<< COMPRA<< endl;
}
else (COMPRA <=1000);
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.05);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON 5% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
```

Entonces, si el valor es inferior a 500 no se aplicará descuento. Si el valor es igual o superior a 500 y, además, es igual o inferior a 1000, entonces se aplicará un 5% de descuento.

Y ahí termina la condición... tu programa sigue ejecutándose y se encuentra con otro condicional diferente:

```
if (COMPRA <= 7000)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.11);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 11% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else (COMPRA <= 15000);
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.18);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 18% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
```

Nota que este segundo condicional es **independiente** del primero, por lo que el mismo se ejecutará independientemente del resultado del primer condicional.

En este caso, si tuvieses un valor de 600 se aplicaría, en el primer condicional, se aplicará un descuento del 5% y, en este segundo, uno adicional del 11%.

Para evitar este problema tienes que concatenar todos los condicionales para que únicamente se ejecute una de las alternativas... y para eso tienes la cadena `if - else if - else if ... else`:

```
if (COMPRA < 500)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA;
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR:"<< COMPRA<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <=1000)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.05);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON 5% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <= 7000)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.11);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 11% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <= 15000)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.18);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 18% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA > 15000)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.25);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 25% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
```

Pero podrías hasta dejarlo más limpio. Fíjate la última condición `if (COMPRA > 15000)`. Esta condición es residual, es decir, si no se ha ejecutado ninguna de las anteriores entonces debería ejecutarse **sí o sí** esta condición... sin excepciones. Este ultimo caso debería dejarse, simplemente, con un `else`:

```
if (COMPRA < 500)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA;
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR:"<< COMPRA<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <=1000)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.05);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON 5% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <= 7000)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.11);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 11% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <= 15000)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.18);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 18% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.25);
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 25% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
```

Adicionalmente, a modo de observación, aplicar un descuento del 5% es equivalente a quedarse con el 95% del valor original, es decir (1 - descuento):

```
if (COMPRA < 500)
{
    PAGAR = COMPRA;
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR:"<< COMPRA<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <=1000)
{
    PAGAR *= 0.95; // 1.0 - 0.05
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON 5% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <= 7000)
{
    PAGAR *= 0.89; // 1.0 - 0.11
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 11% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else if (COMPRA <= 15000)
{
    PAGAR *= 0.82; // 1.0 - 0.18
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 18% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
else
{
    PAGAR *= 0.75; // 1.0 - 0.25
    cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 25% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
}
```

Nota también que si pones un punto y coma detrás del `if` o el `else`, **la condición no se tendrá en cuenta** o, mejor dicho, la condición no afectará a ninguna instrucción:

```
if( 3 > 5 );
  std::cout << "3 es mayor que 5";
```

El siguiente código es equivalente a este otro:

```
if( 3 > 5 )
{
}
std::cout << "3 es mayor que 5";
```

Así es facil entender por qué el mensaje se va a mostrar siempre, cuando es obvio que no debería mostrarse nunca.

Ya sabes, cuidado a la hora de poner punto y coma

Y bueno, el `else` así por las buenas, no comprueba ninguna condición, para eso está el `if`. Luego lo siguiente, por defecto, tampoco es válido:

```
else (COMPRA <=1000);
```

Este código es equivalente al siguiente:

```
else
{
  (COMPRA <= 1000);
}
```

Y, como puedes apreciar, no hace absolutamente nada, ya que el resultado de la comparación no va a ninguna parte... como te he dicho, para eso está el `if`:

```
else if (COMPRA <=1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes colocar `Else if` si quieres una segunda condición en caso de que no se cumpla la primera. Si son dos opciones posibles sería `If` y `else`, pero en este caso tienes varios tipos de opciones debes colocar `if` y `else if`. Lee ***if anidados.***

```
 if (COMPRA < 500){
        PAGAR = COMPRA;
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
 }else if(COMPRA <=1000){
        PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.05);
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON 5% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
 }else if(COMPRA <= 7000){
        PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.11);
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 11% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
 }else if(COMPRA <= 15000){
        PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.18);
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 18% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
 }else{
        PAGAR = COMPRA - (COMPRA * 0.25);
        cout<< "MONTO A PAGAR CON EL 25% DE DESCUENTO:"<< PAGAR<< endl;
 }
```

EDIT: Perdona mi explicación confusa. `if` se usa para comprobar una condición, si no se cumple y colocas un `else`, será lo que ejecutará. En caso de que lo que siga sea otraa condición, deberás colocar `else if(condición)`, y así tantas condiciones tengas. Como te dije, lee más sobre ***if anidados***.

EDIT 2: Supongo que antes validaste que la variable *compra* no pueda ser 0 o números negativos, de no ser así el primer if debería ser:

```
if(COMPRA < 500 && COMPRA > 0)
```

Comment: Puedes poner tantos `else if` como creas oportuno... no veo necesidad de tener dos niveles de `if`. Y el último `else` es incorrecto... los `else` **no pueden tener condicion**

Comment: No me fijé el último else, lo que hice fue copiar el código del que preguntó. Lo de tener colocar así los if->else if->else->if fue como me enseñó un profesor en la universidad y me quedó la costumbre. Gracias por la observación

Comment: Los vicios de los profesores no deberían adquirirlos los alumnos. Esa configuración de `if else` denota código descuidado. No solo no ofrece ninguna mejora sino que además es más largo (tiene una indentación de más), está mal tabulado, es más complicado de leer y más dificil de mantener. Es una pena que los profesores no pongan más énfasis en enseñar a escribir código legible.

Comment: Por cierto... te has dejado un punto y coma detrás del else y el codigo sigue estando mal tabulado. Si tu intención es maquillar el `else { if` te saldría más a cuenta sustituirlo por un `else if`. Así arreglas la tabulación y te ahorras una pareja de llaves

Comment: @AndySamuelAlvarado que el usuario que pregunta tenga malas prácticas no implica que la debes repetir, una respuesta de calidad no solo resuelve el OP sino que tambien señala otros errores, ten en cuenta que otros usuarios tomaran como referencia tu respuesta.

Comment: La ultima validacion esta mal, ya que provocaria que caiga por el else y aplique un descuento totalmente incorrecto. Deberia estar afuera.

Comment: @gbianchi te refieres a la de mayor que 0? Por qué estaría mal?

Comment: Deberias agregar el mayor que cero en todas las condiciones. si no, va a caer en la proxima... En realidad deberias preguntar si es menor que 0 antes de todo esto...

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus comentarios, me sirven de mucho, es primera vez que hago un programa tan extenso como este, y los errores que tengo me ayudaran a ya no cometerlos otra vez, ya pude arreglar mi código, solo tenía que poner el if - else y ya me salía correcto.